# Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhg

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I was implementing the play services module in build.gradle and now I have the following error:

```
    Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhg found in      modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play- services-measurement-impl-20.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:20.0.2)
```

I tried cleaning the project but it didn't worked

This is my build.gradle file

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-rc01'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is 2 colliding package issue,

When including 2 google play services packages. It is intercepting each other.

So that use this line;

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
```

Also you can use,

```
buildTypes {
   release {
     shrinkResources true
   }
}
```

Comment: Why should I `shrinkResources`??